# FCM Error of Invalid argument and Bad device token

Tags: java, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried to achieve FCM in Springboot. The front end will call a post request to the backend and pass the message object. Then the message will be extracted and sent to the firbase cloud.

The following image shows the message object (top of the image) and the error detail:
[image]

This is how I send the message:

```
Notification notification = Notification
                .builder()
                .setTitle(pushMessage.getTitle())
                .setBody(pushMessage.getBody())
                //.setImage(pushMessage.getImage())
                .build();

        Message message = Message
                .builder()
                .setToken(pushMessage.getRegistrationToken())
                .setNotification(notification)
                .putAllData(pushMessage.getData())
                .build();
        try{
            firebaseMessaging.send(message);
            return "Successfully Send!";
        }catch (FirebaseMessagingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Error Send!!!!";
        }
```

Also, there is another Bad Device Token error:
[image]

I tried to search for solutions but I found my situation was different from simple invalid argument. I tried to renew the registration token but the problem is still... Where is the problem?